# setTimeout function with keypress pause Overload

Tags: javascript, html, timer

Hi i have a function that is reloading the messages within a div using a timer. Iv tried every possible method that i can get my head round to have a stable timer, but  almost every attempt has the timer maxing out running multiple times instead of a stable 1 every 4 seconds. I cannot see what i am doing wrong.

The timer works up until i hit a key , then after the timer restarts i get multiple timers running in the console output.

Can anybody help guide me towards a workable model.

Thank you.

Here is trhe code.

```
$(window.ready = function(){


var ticker = function (){ 

    var varLISTID = "<?php echo $listID; ?>";
    var varUSERACCOUNTNAME = "<?php echo $useraccountname; ?>";
    var varITEMACCOUNTNAME = "<?php echo $itemaccountname; ?>";
    var varSELECTEDUSER=document.getElementById('datacatchuser').getAttribute("data-variable-SELECTEDUSER");


    var mybutton= "messageboxreplybutton.php?listID=" + varLISTID + "&useraccountname=" + varUSERACCOUNTNAME + "&itemaccountname=" + varITEMACCOUNTNAME + "&selecteduser=" + varSELECTEDUSER;
    $('#buttonbox').load(mybutton);

    var mylink = "loadmessages.php?listID=" + varLISTID + "&useraccountname=" + varUSERACCOUNTNAME + "&itemaccountname=" + varITEMACCOUNTNAME + "&selecteduser=" + varSELECTEDUSER;
    $('#infobox1').load(mylink);

    var myotherlink = "contactselect.php?listID=" + varLISTID + "&useraccountname=" + varUSERACCOUNTNAME + "&itemaccountname=" + varITEMACCOUNTNAME + "&selecteduser=" + varSELECTEDUSER; 
    $('#containercontact').load(myotherlink);
            console.log('running');
};//10s



var myTimer = window.setTimeout(ticker, 4000);

   //stops running until ???
   $(document).keypress(function() {

           window.clearInterval(myTimer);

           setTimeout( function(){
              var myTimer = window.setTimeout(ticker, 4000);

            },4000)
   })


});
```

Comment: its clearTimeout not interval.

Comment: yeah , but eitherway i get the same problem// infact setInterval is worse as it builds up regardless of the pause on keypress... I get as many timers as keypresses

Comment: that's not really clear what you're doing. You start defining a first timeout, so after 4 seconds it will execute the ticker function. But on keypress, you clear the previous interval (should be clearTimeout?) , and then you set a new timeout (its reference gets lost because you don't store it) that after 4 seconds executes a function which sets a new timeout again (in a new variable because you're using var again so you won't clear it) that after 4 seconds execute the ticker function.

Comment: No change im afraid, could the problem be because its running in a $(window.ready = function(){

Comment: I told you above the issue and the answer of @markmeyer shows the right way to do it

Comment: iv tried all but the right way, what i present at present was suggested online,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a variable (the second time) with

```
 var myTimer = window.setTimeout(ticker, 4000);
```

inside a function, you create a new variable local to that function, which is then in accessible later, so you can't clear it. This is why you're ending up with multiple running timers. If you just use one variable that points to the current running interval, you can then clear it before you start another:

```js
function ticker() {
  console.log("timer fired")
}
var myTimer = setInterval(ticker, 1000);

//stops running until ???
$(document).keypress(function() {
  console.log("clearing")
  clearInterval(myTimer);
  // don't use var, just access the existing variable from the parent scope.
  myTimer = setInterval(ticker, 1000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To run it just once, unless there's a keypress, you can just replace `setInterval` with `setTimeout`. This will set a 4 second timer. If there's a keypress, it will cancel the first timeout and reset another.

```js
   function ticker() {
      console.log("timer fired")
    }
    var myTimer = setTimeout(ticker, 4000);

    //stops running until ???
    $(document).keypress(function() {
      console.log("resetting timeout")
      clearTimeout(myTimer);
      // don't use var, just access the existing variable from the parent scope.
      myTimer = setTimeout(ticker, 4000);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: he has also an extra (not needed) timeout here: `setTimeout( function(){
              var myTimer = window.setTimeout(ticker, 4000);

            },4000)`

Comment: I know @quirimmo, I took that out because it just it made it it harder to show specifically what was wrong. It doesn't change anything if you add it back — just delays the start of the next interval.

Comment: nope sorry, I meant that your solution is also better because you don't use an extra timeout, not needed, which never gets cleared in his code

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks @quirimmo

Comment: right then the problem is because it looping with the $(window.ready = function(){  
   "(Mark Meyer Code)"   });

Comment: iv used the above suggestion but its within a $(window.ready = function(){ }   so its re-iterating over n over again regardless.

Comment: How do i execute the ticker function just once  with no user input , so it can do its thing without using $(window.ready = function(){ }

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
  ticker();
})` you need this wrapper because in that function you are accessing the DOM, which is ready inside this callback.

Comment: @lezz see the edit for a way to use `setTimeout` to run `ticker` once.

Comment: ok i sorted it, thank you Mark Meyer, you were correct, i had to move my function out of the same page i was reloading (loadmessages.php) this was the problem